# How to get data on minute base instead of hourly base?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, truncate

I use the following query to get my data counted on hourly base:

```
select to_char(trunc(time, 'HH'), 'DD/MM/YY HH24') as "date",
count(event), count(distinct id) from source
where time >= date '2021-01-01'
group by trunc(time,'HH')
order by trunc(time,'HH');
```

What I now want to do is the same but on minute base. How can I get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, you could have avoided `trunc` entirely as you use `TO_CHAR` anyway:

```
select to_char(time, 'dd/mm/yy hh24') ...
```

If you want to include minutes, no problem:

```
select to_char(time, 'dd/mm/yy hh24:mi') as "date",
       count(event), count(distinct id)
from source
where ...
group by to_char(time, 'dd/mm/yy hh24:mi')
```

Note that sorting by **strings** probably won't produce desired results. Perhaps, if you'd change date format to e.g. `'yyyymmdd hh24:mi'`